# How to make XAML border to stick to the element?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a C# chess app, and I want to make a border to the chess board, but there is a big space between the border and the chess board.

The XAML code:

```
<Grid>
   
    <Border BorderBrush="SaddleBrown" BorderThickness="2">
        <local:ChessBoard x:Name ="chessBoard"/>
    </Border>
       
</Grid>
```

The ChessBoard element extends grid and has its `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` set to `Center`.

This is how it looks:
[The look of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xy34.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following aligment attributes to the Border

```
 VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
```

In full code:

```
<Grid>
   
    <Border BorderBrush="SaddleBrown" BorderThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <local:ChessBoard x:Name ="chessBoard"/>
    </Border>
       
</Grid>
```